# Do films "buy" special effects parts to avoid all the budget to film those?

Tags: film-techniques, effects

I was watching the making-of of a movie and one of the actors mentioned that they had a very low budget. Then the movie contained a situation where a car was falling down a cliff, exploded and all those effects.

I don't know how low the budget was, but I guess that filming a car in such situation may involve quite a lot of money.

[Wikipedia on Low-budget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-budget_film) film says:

> (...) Science fiction films, which were once the domain of B movies, frequently require a big budget to accommodate their special effects, but low-cost do-it-yourself [computer-generated imagery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-generated_imagery) can make them affordable, especially when they focus on story and characterization. Plot devices like shooting as found footage can lower production costs, and scripts that rely on extended dialogue, such as Reservoir Dogs or Sex, Lies, and Videotape, can entertain audiences without many sets.

So this would mean that people in production of these movies may require some CGI-fu (computer generated imagery). But what if they do not have access to those?

Similar discussions arise in Reddit's [What low budget movie has impressive visual effects?](https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/7f3ejb/what_low_budget_movie_has_impressive_visual/)

For this, I wonder: how common is for movies to "buy" visual effects from some kind of database of sources, so that they don't have to make all of it by themselves? If so, is there any chance that several films share specific moments?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_footage

Comment: Do a search for available apps on your phone’s store using search phrases like “movie fx”.  You’ll find a few apps that will let you add special effects (explosions, aliens, etc) while you are videoing.  Some of the makers of these sorts of apps are well known movie studios.   If this is what’s available for a few bucks on a phone, even low budget movies will have much more powerful software in reach.

Comment: Low budget doesn't mean low talent. I worked on a movie with [almost] literally zero budget. They persuaded people to donate their time [& their own facilities] to help make the movie, including some decent CGI fx. They even got Brian May to do the soundtrack.

Comment: Oh, @BCdotWEB, that is it! Mind posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by [BCdotWeb](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/13595/bcdotweb) in comments, such thing exists and is called Stock footage.

The summary text on its [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_footage) explains it quite well:

> Stock footage, and similarly, archive footage, library pictures, and file footage is film or video footage that can be used again in other films. Stock footage is beneficial to filmmakers as it saves shooting new material. A single piece of stock footage is called a "stock shot" or a "library shot". Stock footage may have appeared in previous productions but may also be outtakes or footage shot for previous productions and not used. Examples of stock footage that might be utilized are moving images of cities and landmarks, wildlife in their natural environments, and historical footage. Suppliers of stock footage may be either rights managed or royalty-free. Many websites offer direct downloads of clips in various formats.

Regarding the pricing and reusability, it also states that:

> One of the largest producers of public domain stock footage is the United States government. All videos produced by the United States military, NASA, and other agencies are available for use as stock footage. There are a number of companies that own the copyrights to large libraries of stock footage and charge filmmakers a fee for using it, but they rarely demand royalties. Stock footage comes from a myriad of sources including the public domain, other movies and television programs, news outlets, and purpose-shot stock footage.